# Erro com Map<String, dynamic> - Não consegue reconhecer String como dynamic

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estou com o seguinte erro no Flutter:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Esse erro está ocorrendo quando eu tendo executar o seginte código:

```
  List _listaTarefas = [];
  _salvarArquivo() async{

        final diretorio = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        var arquivo =  File("${diretorio.path}/dados.json" );

        Map<String, dynamic> tarefa = Map();
        tarefa["titulo"] = "Ir ao Mercado";
        tarefa["realizada"] = false;
        _listaTarefas.add(tarefa);

        String dados = json.encode(_listaTarefas);
        arquivo.writeAsString(dados);

  }
```

Comment: Pessoal, descobri o problema:
Ali onde está 
`List _listaTarefas = [];`
deve ser 
`List<dynamic> _listaTarefas = [];` .

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo que você já tenha encontrado uma solução para o seu problema, deixarei aqui igualmente uma proposta para melhorar o seu código, e manter uma arquitetura limpa, de maneira que seja mais fácil para você mesmo entender o que você está escrevendo:

Se você tem uma lista de tarefas, e o tipo que será inserido nesta lista é sempre um `Map<String, dynamic>`, agora é melhor você definir a lista como:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _listaTarefas = [];
```

Deste modo, somente *Map* com aquele formato pode ser inserido, mas ok, já entendemos, pelo nome da variável, que esta é uma lista de tarefas, mas como é formada uma tarefa? Quais valores podem ter? Como eu posso me lembrar destes valores em 1 semana, 1 mês, sem ter que procurar por um arquivo de tarefas para saber como é estruturado? Por sorte, [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) é uma linguagem *tipizada* e *Object-Oriented*, agora que tal fazermos uma classe que representa uma a estrutura de uma tarefa:

```
class Tarefa{
  String titulo;
  bool realizada;

  Tarefa(this.titulo, this.realizada);

  Map<String, dynamic> get toMap => {
    'titulo': titulo,
    'realizada': realizada
  }

  String get toJsonString => json.encode(this.toMap);
}
```

E agora podemos mudar a lista para:

```
List<Tarefa> _listaTarefas = [];
```

E com isso o seu método `_salvarArquivo` pode ser simplificado desta maneira:

```
_salvarArquivo() async{
  final diretorio = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var arquivo =  File("${diretorio.path}/dados.json" );

  Tarefa tarefa = Tarefa("Ir ao Mercado", false);
  _listaTarefas.add(tarefa);
  arquivo.writeAsString(tarefa.toJsonString);
}
```

Se você tiver uma classe com muitos atributos, [Json Serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) pode simplificar a sua vida gerando a maior parte do código de conversão entre objetos para você.